# Is stream_socket_client() thread-safe?

Tags: php, sockets, thread-safety

I cannot find if [`stream_socket_client()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) and the associated [`fsockopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) are reasonable thread-safe in recent PHP versions (>5.3).

I am mostly interested in PHP on Apache, in Linux. And also in whether or not Apache MPM-prefork makes a difference, and if knowledge exists if this all holds true for fastCGI under e.g. Nginx.

A short test, shows me that each fork will create its own socket-file, but does this hold true for more concurrent connections? Is that due to the nature of Apache's forking, Unix's socket architecture or PHP itself? I am pretty clueless when it comes to these close-to-the-metal-issues.

Or: is it safe to assume that when reading and writing to sources with `stream_socket_client()` will never collide over different connections?

Comment: PHP does threads?  This is news to me...and even your description seems to indicate you're using processes rather than threads. (Threads don't "fork"; processes do.)

Comment: Is PHP thread safe? Some say *"not yet"* regardless what is printed on the box. -- anyway, would be cool if you would extend the tests you already started to do. Bump it to the max.

Comment: @cHao AFAICT not PHP, but the server around it, hence my question about how apache MPM-prefork fits in this picture.

Comment: @berkes: MPM-prefork is a multi-process MPM.  AFAIK it doesn't thread, so any thread-safety issues are quite irrelevant.

Comment: @cHao if you make that an answer, we can discuss it there, instead of turning the comments into a chat, 'cause I have some questions about what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to pthreads:

PHP's architecture at this point is set in stone - read about PHP6 - so the fact is that the only way you'll be able to thread in anything you recognize as PHP now or in the future is by means of a PECL extension, but you shouldn't let that put you off - you wouldn't withold the abilities of APC from your network simply because it's not part of the core. I might be a bit biased, on account of I am the sole author of pthreads, but I haven't used voodoo or spells, what I've used is the Objects API, combined with TSRM and obviously the extension API - all things that have been in the making for many years and have billions of hours of real world testing, that's not to say that pthreads is production ready, it is certainly not, but some day it will be.

pthreads will not likely ever share resources, I have experimented at length with this, and I have found multiple ways to make it work, but none that are satisfactory. PHP is mostly extensions ( even the standard library is implemented as an extension - it's the most effective way of adding functionality ), and they are all unprepared for an object level multi-threaded environment. For so many reasons, PHP is not a good candidate for multi-threaded network applications. When you think in a non-linear fashion, why would you want to share a resource, (sockets aside - use something more suitable) the resource can be created and manipulated in an entirely different thread while you get on with the business of parsing your templates or json or whatever it is your application does. With that in mind I do not feel compelled to make sharing resources a priority or even a goal of pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

PHP itself has very little support for threads.  It may or may not make promises about functions that are "thread safe", but that makes precious little difference when the interpreter itself pretends threads don't exist.<sup>*</sup>

As far as mpm_prefork is concerned, though, it doesn't matter.  The Prefork MPM is all about *forking* (hence the name).  It doesn't bother with threads, so PHP's thread safety issues don't really come up.

I don't know much about FastCGI (particularly how it differs from old-school CGI), but unless it requires lots of special support from the interpreter, it also will use a multi-process model rather than a multi-thread one.  Each interpreter will have its own process, which makes PHP's support for threads all but irrelevant.

<sup>* There is a PECL module that gives PHP a way to use pthreads, but it's not part of the core, and i imagine there are a whole bunch of extensions that break all to hell when threads come into play.  I consider threading in PHP nowhere near mature enough for production use, and will probably continue to feel that way until PHP itself provides a way to create a thread.</sup>